# How can I check if a response is a user in the server? discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, bots, discord.py

I made a prompt for my bot, I need to make my bot check if the response is an actual id in the server, or a usermention.

This is what it does: It's usless as you can see, but instead of the response it should output an error.

[image: Useless prompt seen in it's natural habitat]

How can I check for it, here's what I have so far:

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages = True)
async def watch(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Please mention the user or send the ID of the user you would like to watch!")
    await client.wait_for('message')
    def check(m):
        return m.author == ctx.author and m.channnel == ctx.channel
    await ctx.send("Please Describe the situation")
    await client.wait_for("message")
    def check(m):
        return m.author == ctx.author and m.channnel == ctx.channel
    await ctx.send("On It!")
```

Answer (score 1):

## Using  client.get_user()

use `get_user` inside `try`. if it couldn't find user with id, it will break.

```
try:
    user = ctx.guild.get_user(user_id)
except:
    ctx.send("not a valid user id")
    return
```

and, if you add it to code, it will look like this:

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages = True)
async def watch(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Please mention the user or send the ID of the user you would like to watch!")
    
    def check(m):
        return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel
    
    user_id = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
    
    try:
        user = ctx.guild.get_user(user_id)
    except:
        ctx.send("not a valid user id")
        return
    
    await ctx.send("Please Describe the situation")
    
    situation = await client.wait_for("message", check=check)
    await ctx.send("On It!")
    print(user_id + "-" + situation)
```

Comment: try `client.fetch_user(id)`

Comment: explain where is the error thrown, in the error handling or getting the user?

Comment: It should be `ctx.guild.get_member(123456)`. If the member is not in the guild it will be `None`

Comment: try now @FakeBlob

Comment: await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/fakeblob/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 859, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/home/fakeblob/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Message' and 'str'
@BillyDev